# How can I filter the card bootstrap HTMLDivElement properly?

Tags: javascript, html, filter, toggle

I am creating a filtering function. With this function we want to filter the application cards, but I cannot display the element properly. The function does not show part of the filtered card, button, picture or text. I know that by placing "#myDIV *" in the .filter function it will search all the elements, even knowing this, I have not found the right way to do it.
Can anybody help me?

I have tried with the code below:

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();    
                $("#myDIV *").filter(function () {
                    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() != "abrir") {
                        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/images/favicon.png">
    <title>SGR - Desktop</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/libs/toastr/build/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/libs/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/dist/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="lds-ripple">
            <div class="lds-pos"></div>
            <div class="lds-pos"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="page-breadcrumb">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex no-block align-items-center">
                        


    <div class="header-title">
        <h1>
            Home
                    <small>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        Desktop
                    </small>
        </h1>
    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
<input class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
    <div  id="myDIV"  class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="emulador project64">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">emulador project64</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">project64.exe</p>
                                <a href="project64.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="overwatch">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">overwatch</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">overwatch.exe</p>
                                <a href="overwatch.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="YouTube">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/images/YouTube.png">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">YouTube</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Google Inc.</p>
                                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Canal de Denuncias">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Canal de Denuncias</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">https://www.canaldedenuncia.cl/cda/metro/cdpages/Inicio.aspx</p>
                                <a href="https://www.canaldedenuncia.cl/cda/metro/cdpages/Inicio.aspx" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Cipher">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Cipher</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">www.cipher.cl</p>
                                <a href="www.cipher.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Terraria">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Terraria</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">shared/terraria.exe</p>
                                <a href="shared/terraria.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Revista And&#233;n">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Revista And&#233;n</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://nt25_intranet/archivos/revistas/2017-03/revista.pdf</p>
                                <a href="http://nt25_intranet/archivos/revistas/2017-03/revista.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Smov2">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Smov2</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">\\NT1_METRO\Aplicacion\Operaciones\smov2\SMOV 2.exe</p>
                                <a href="\\NT1_METRO\Aplicacion\Operaciones\smov2\SMOV 2.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Concursos internos">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Concursos internos</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">https://metro.openagora.cl/</p>
                                <a href="https://metro.openagora.cl/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="The Clinic">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">The Clinic</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">www.theclinic.cl</p>
                                <a href="www.theclinic.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Hotmail">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Hotmail</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://www.hotmail.com</p>
                                <a href="http://www.hotmail.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Gmail">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Gmail</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://www.gmail.com</p>
                                <a href="http://www.gmail.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="CNN">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">CNN</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">www.cnn.org</p>
                                <a href="www.cnn.org" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Metro Familia">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Metro Familia</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://andensocial.metro.cl/aplicaciones-generales/metro-en-familia</p>
                                <a href="http://andensocial.metro.cl/aplicaciones-generales/metro-en-familia" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="League of Legends">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">League of Legends</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">lollauncher.exe</p>
                                <a href="lollauncher.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Minecraft Java Edition">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Minecraft Java Edition</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">minecraft.exe</p>
                                <a href="minecraft.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Webmail Metro">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Webmail Metro</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">https://mail.metro.cl/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&amp;url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.metro.cl%2fowa%2f</p>
                                <a href="https://mail.metro.cl/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&amp;url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.metro.cl%2fowa%2f" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Autoconsulta ESS">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Autoconsulta ESS</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://172.16.20.60:84/sse_generico/espanol/generico_login.jsp?estado=0</p>
                                <a href="http://172.16.20.60:84/sse_generico/espanol/generico_login.jsp?estado=0" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="And&#233;n Social">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">And&#233;n Social</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://andensocial.metro.cl</p>
                                <a href="http://andensocial.metro.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Sitio Conductores">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Sitio Conductores</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://operaciones.metrosantiago.cl/</p>
                                <a href="http://operaciones.metrosantiago.cl/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
    </div>
</div>



            </div>
            <footer class="footer text-center">
<div class="modal" id="loginModal"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"><div class="modal-content">                    <div id="login"></div>
</div></div></div>                
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="/assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/extra-libs/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
    <!--Wave Effects -->
    <script src="/dist/js/waves.js"></script>
    <!--Menu sidebar -->
    <script src="/dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
    <!--Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="/dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/core.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/bootbox/bootbox.js"></script>

    <!--This page JavaScript -->
    <!-- <script src="~/dist/js/pages/dashboards/dashboard1.js"></script> -->
    <!-- Charts js Files -->

    <!--Success Modal Templates-->
<div class="modal fade modal-message modal-success" id="modal-success"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
</div><div class="modal-title">        Correcto
</div><div class="modal-body">        La solicitud se efectuó con éxito
</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-success " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Aceptar</button></div></div></div></div>
<!--End Success Modal Templates-->
<!--Info Modal Templates-->
<div class="modal fade modal-message modal-info" id="modal-info"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div><div class="modal-title">        Información
</div><div class="modal-body">        Se le notifica información importante
</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-info " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div></div></div></div><!--End Info Modal Templates-->
<!--Danger Modal Templates-->
<div class="modal fade modal-message modal-danger" id="modal-danger"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i>
</div><div class="modal-title">        Error
</div><div class="modal-body">        Se ha producido un error
</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-danger " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div></div></div></div><!--End Danger Modal Templates-->
<!--Warning Modal Templates-->
<div class="modal fade modal-message modal-warning" id="modal-warning"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">        <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
</div><div class="modal-title">        Alerta
</div><div class="modal-body">        Algo ha salido mal
</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-warning " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div></div></div></div><!--End Warning Modal Templates-->
<!--Confirm Modal Templates-->
<div id="core_modalconfirmdialog" style="display:none;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Mensaje
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Mensaje que iría en el centro
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Confirm Modal Templates-->


</body>

</html>
```

[image: Filtered elements]

[image: Not filtered elements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first hide all cards while typing and only show the ones based on the search query. To simplify your filter a bit you could use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("div[class^=col]")
      .hide()
      .filter(function() {
        var cardTitle = $(this).find('.card-title').text().toLowerCase();

        return cardTitle.includes(value);
      })
      .show();
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Favicon icon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/images/favicon.png">
  <title>SGR - Desktop</title>
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="/assets/libs/toastr/build/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/assets/libs/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/dist/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <div class="preloader">
    <div class="lds-ripple">
      <div class="lds-pos"></div>
      <div class="lds-pos"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="page-breadcrumb">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 d-flex no-block align-items-center">



            <div class="header-title">
              <h1>
                Home
                <small>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        Desktop
                    </small>
              </h1>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">


        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>

        </style>
        <input class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="container">
          <div id="myDIV" class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="emulador project64">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">emulador project64</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">project64.exe</p>
                  <a href="project64.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="overwatch">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">overwatch</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">overwatch.exe</p>
                  <a href="overwatch.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="YouTube">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/images/YouTube.png">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">YouTube</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Google Inc.</p>
                  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Canal de Denuncias">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Canal de Denuncias</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">https://www.canaldedenuncia.cl/cda/metro/cdpages/Inicio.aspx</p>
                  <a href="https://www.canaldedenuncia.cl/cda/metro/cdpages/Inicio.aspx" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Cipher">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Cipher</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">www.cipher.cl</p>
                  <a href="www.cipher.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Terraria">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Terraria</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">shared/terraria.exe</p>
                  <a href="shared/terraria.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Revista And&#233;n">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Revista And&#233;n</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">http://nt25_intranet/archivos/revistas/2017-03/revista.pdf</p>
                  <a href="http://nt25_intranet/archivos/revistas/2017-03/revista.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Smov2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Smov2</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">\\NT1_METRO\Aplicacion\Operaciones\smov2\SMOV 2.exe</p>
                  <a href="\\NT1_METRO\Aplicacion\Operaciones\smov2\SMOV 2.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Concursos internos">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Concursos internos</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">https://metro.openagora.cl/</p>
                  <a href="https://metro.openagora.cl/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="The Clinic">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">The Clinic</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">www.theclinic.cl</p>
                  <a href="www.theclinic.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Hotmail">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Hotmail</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">http://www.hotmail.com</p>
                  <a href="http://www.hotmail.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Gmail">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Gmail</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">http://www.gmail.com</p>
                  <a href="http://www.gmail.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="CNN">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">CNN</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">www.cnn.org</p>
                  <a href="www.cnn.org" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Metro Familia">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Metro Familia</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">http://andensocial.metro.cl/aplicaciones-generales/metro-en-familia</p>
                  <a href="http://andensocial.metro.cl/aplicaciones-generales/metro-en-familia" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="League of Legends">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">League of Legends</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">lollauncher.exe</p>
                  <a href="lollauncher.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Minecraft Java Edition">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Minecraft Java Edition</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">minecraft.exe</p>
                  <a href="minecraft.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Webmail Metro">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Webmail Metro</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">https://mail.metro.cl/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&amp;url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.metro.cl%2fowa%2f</p>
                  <a href="https://mail.metro.cl/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&amp;url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.metro.cl%2fowa%2f" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Autoconsulta ESS">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Autoconsulta ESS</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">http://172.16.20.60:84/sse_generico/espanol/generico_login.jsp?estado=0</p>
                  <a href="http://172.16.20.60:84/sse_generico/espanol/generico_login.jsp?estado=0" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="And&#233;n Social">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">And&#233;n Social</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">http://andensocial.metro.cl</p>
                  <a href="http://andensocial.metro.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="card" id="Sitio Conductores">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Sitio Conductores</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">http://operaciones.metrosantiago.cl/</p>
                  <a href="http://operaciones.metrosantiago.cl/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
      <footer class="footer text-center">
        <div class="modal" id="loginModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div id="login"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="/assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/extra-libs/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
  <!--Wave Effects -->
  <script src="/dist/js/waves.js"></script>
  <!--Menu sidebar -->
  <script src="/dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
  <!--Custom JavaScript -->
  <script src="/dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/js/core.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/libs/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/libs/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/libs/bootbox/bootbox.js"></script>

  <!--This page JavaScript -->
  <!-- <script src="~/dist/js/pages/dashboards/dashboard1.js"></script> -->
  <!-- Charts js Files -->

  <!--Success Modal Templates-->
  <div class="modal fade modal-message modal-success" id="modal-success">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"> <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-title"> Correcto
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> La solicitud se efectuó con éxito
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-success " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Aceptar</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End Success Modal Templates-->
  <!--Info Modal Templates-->
  <div class="modal fade modal-message modal-info" id="modal-info">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-title"> Información
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> Se le notifica información importante
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-info " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End Info Modal Templates-->
  <!--Danger Modal Templates-->
  <div class="modal fade modal-message modal-danger" id="modal-danger">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-title"> Error
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> Se ha producido un error
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-danger " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End Danger Modal Templates-->
  <!--Warning Modal Templates-->
  <div class="modal fade modal-message modal-warning" id="modal-warning">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"> <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-title"> Alerta
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> Algo ha salido mal
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-warning " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End Warning Modal Templates-->
  <!--Confirm Modal Templates-->
  <div id="core_modalconfirmdialog" style="display:none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Mensaje
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Mensaje que iría en el centro
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Confirm Modal Templates-->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your response Carl.
Yes, I tried it, but there are some problems:

- For example, if you try to search for "abrir", no element is filtered because all the elements have the word "abrir".

- Filtered items are not displayed correctly.


I need to filter only by the "card-title". :(

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look and let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks Carl but the function does not order the elements correctly, because I hide the card and not the parent column. I included "this.parentNode" and now it works correctly. Thank you

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect your last comment. Please mark this answer as correct if all your problems have been resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#box').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(valThis === ""){
        $('.library_card > div').show();
    } else {
        $('.library_card > div').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
   };
});



// #box-- inpuut type text id
// .library_card -- div class
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your response Soumyanjan. There are some problems: - For example, if you try to search for "abrir", no element is filtered because all the elements have the word "abrir".

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to solve the problem and prevent the cards from being displayed incorrectly:

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
                    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                    $(".card").filter(function () {
                        $(this.parentNode).toggle($(this).find('.card-title').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                    });
                });
            });
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

  .card {
        min-height: 250px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/images/favicon.png">
    <title>SGR - Desktop</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/libs/toastr/build/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/libs/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/dist/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="lds-ripple">
            <div class="lds-pos"></div>
            <div class="lds-pos"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="page-breadcrumb">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex no-block align-items-center">
                        


    <div class="header-title">
        <h1>
            Home
                    <small>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        Desktop
                    </small>
        </h1>
    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
<input class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
    <div  id="myDIV"  class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="emulador project64">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">emulador project64</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">project64.exe</p>
                                <a href="project64.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="overwatch">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">overwatch</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">overwatch.exe</p>
                                <a href="overwatch.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="YouTube">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/images/YouTube.png">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">YouTube</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Google Inc.</p>
                                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Canal de Denuncias">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Canal de Denuncias</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">https://www.canaldedenuncia.cl/cda/metro/cdpages/Inicio.aspx</p>
                                <a href="https://www.canaldedenuncia.cl/cda/metro/cdpages/Inicio.aspx" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Cipher">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Cipher</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">www.cipher.cl</p>
                                <a href="www.cipher.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Terraria">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Terraria</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">shared/terraria.exe</p>
                                <a href="shared/terraria.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Revista And&#233;n">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Revista And&#233;n</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://nt25_intranet/archivos/revistas/2017-03/revista.pdf</p>
                                <a href="http://nt25_intranet/archivos/revistas/2017-03/revista.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Smov2">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Smov2</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">\\NT1_METRO\Aplicacion\Operaciones\smov2\SMOV 2.exe</p>
                                <a href="\\NT1_METRO\Aplicacion\Operaciones\smov2\SMOV 2.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Concursos internos">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Concursos internos</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">https://metro.openagora.cl/</p>
                                <a href="https://metro.openagora.cl/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="The Clinic">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">The Clinic</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">www.theclinic.cl</p>
                                <a href="www.theclinic.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Hotmail">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Hotmail</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://www.hotmail.com</p>
                                <a href="http://www.hotmail.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Gmail">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Gmail</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://www.gmail.com</p>
                                <a href="http://www.gmail.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="CNN">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">CNN</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">www.cnn.org</p>
                                <a href="www.cnn.org" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Metro Familia">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Metro Familia</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://andensocial.metro.cl/aplicaciones-generales/metro-en-familia</p>
                                <a href="http://andensocial.metro.cl/aplicaciones-generales/metro-en-familia" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="League of Legends">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">League of Legends</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">lollauncher.exe</p>
                                <a href="lollauncher.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Minecraft Java Edition">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Minecraft Java Edition</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">minecraft.exe</p>
                                <a href="minecraft.exe" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Webmail Metro">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Webmail Metro</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">https://mail.metro.cl/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&amp;url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.metro.cl%2fowa%2f</p>
                                <a href="https://mail.metro.cl/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&amp;url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.metro.cl%2fowa%2f" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Autoconsulta ESS">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Autoconsulta ESS</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://172.16.20.60:84/sse_generico/espanol/generico_login.jsp?estado=0</p>
                                <a href="http://172.16.20.60:84/sse_generico/espanol/generico_login.jsp?estado=0" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="And&#233;n Social">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">And&#233;n Social</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://andensocial.metro.cl</p>
                                <a href="http://andensocial.metro.cl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="card" id="Sitio Conductores">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Sitio Conductores</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">http://operaciones.metrosantiago.cl/</p>
                                <a href="http://operaciones.metrosantiago.cl/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary">Abrir</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
    </div>
</div>



            </div>
            <footer class="footer text-center">
<div class="modal" id="loginModal"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"><div class="modal-content">                    <div id="login"></div>
</div></div></div>                
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="/assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/extra-libs/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
    <!--Wave Effects -->
    <script src="/dist/js/waves.js"></script>
    <!--Menu sidebar -->
    <script src="/dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
    <!--Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="/dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/core.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/libs/bootbox/bootbox.js"></script>

    <!--This page JavaScript -->
    <!-- <script src="~/dist/js/pages/dashboards/dashboard1.js"></script> -->
    <!-- Charts js Files -->

    <!--Success Modal Templates-->
<div class="modal fade modal-message modal-success" id="modal-success"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
</div><div class="modal-title">        Correcto
</div><div class="modal-body">        La solicitud se efectuó con éxito
</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-success " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Aceptar</button></div></div></div></div>
<!--End Success Modal Templates-->
<!--Info Modal Templates-->
<div class="modal fade modal-message modal-info" id="modal-info"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div><div class="modal-title">        Información
</div><div class="modal-body">        Se le notifica información importante
</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-info " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div></div></div></div><!--End Info Modal Templates-->
<!--Danger Modal Templates-->
<div class="modal fade modal-message modal-danger" id="modal-danger"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i>
</div><div class="modal-title">        Error
</div><div class="modal-body">        Se ha producido un error
</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-danger " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div></div></div></div><!--End Danger Modal Templates-->
<!--Warning Modal Templates-->
<div class="modal fade modal-message modal-warning" id="modal-warning"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">        <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
</div><div class="modal-title">        Alerta
</div><div class="modal-body">        Algo ha salido mal
</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-warning " data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ok</button></div></div></div></div><!--End Warning Modal Templates-->
<!--Confirm Modal Templates-->
<div id="core_modalconfirmdialog" style="display:none;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Mensaje
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Mensaje que iría en el centro
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Confirm Modal Templates-->


</body>

</html>
```